# Как вытащить цифры между буквами PHP?

Tags: php

Из строки №Дн025П1 нужно вытащить при помощи регулярки 025.

Рассчитывал, что такой пример отработает:

```
preg_match('/[А-Яа-я](.*)[А-Яа-я]/Uis', $str, $out);
```

но - нет.

Помогите правильно составить регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$STRING = '№Дн025П1';
preg_match_all('/№([А-Яа-я]+)([0-9]+)([А-Яа-я]+)/iuU', $STRING, $OUT, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($OUT);
```

Необходимый элемент массива думаю найдете сами

Comment: Спасибо. Только оказалось, что могут быть еще и такие варианты: №1, №Дн153

Comment: `/№([А-Яа-я]+)([0-9]+)([А-Яа-я]*)/iu`

Comment: Лучше, только №1 ничего не выводит

Comment: @Сергей вы определитесь под какие вам ситуации, так вечность можно. сразу полный список вариантов дайте.

Comment: @Сергей `/№([А-Яа-я]*)([0-9]+)([А-Яа-я]*)/iu`

Comment: Я ж выше комментировал: "Спасибо. Только оказалось, что могут быть еще и такие варианты: №1, №Дн153"

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант с использованием ретроспективной положительной проверки - будут найдены все вхождения в подстроке:

```
$str = '№1, №Дн153, №Дн025П1';

preg_match_all('~(?<=Дн)\d+~', $str, $out);
var_export($out[0]);
```

Результат:

```
array (
  0 => '153',
  1 => '025',
)
```